# Send user to REQUEST_URI after Oauth Login

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm using the Google PHP client library to authenticate users into a site. Using very close to the example [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app)

However, users are always redirected to the homepage after login, i.e. `site.com/`.

**What is the correct way to bounce users to the requested url after login, e.g. `site.com/requested-uri` ?**

I've tried to pass a query parameter along on the initial request through `index.php`:

`$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php?redirect=' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Then pass it to the example code from the docs:

```
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
parse_str($uri['query'], $query);
$redirect = $query['redirect'];

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $redirect;
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

However, it still is redirecting without the requested URI.

I feel like there must be a way to do this built in to the PHP library. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: The query parameter gets lost because Google sends users twice through `oauth2callback.php` once to get the code, then a second time to authenticate the request. On the second trip Google will only accept whitelisted URLs from the API Console, which fails with the query parameter

Comment: have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$client->setState($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);`. After the authentication you can receive the state from `$_GET['state']`.

I don't know if this method is correct but I am using it on my application.